# Split prefix and surname (based on array data)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column of data existing out of names, which may or may not contain a surname prefix. Those prefixes can exist out of multiple words. I have a list of all possible prefixes, but now I need to split the prefix and surname and make 2 columns with the data.

What I did was writing an excel formula like the following:

```
=IF(
   RIGHT(A1;7) = " van de"
 ;
   RIGHT(A1;6)
 ;
   IF(
     RIGHT(A1;4) = " van"
   ;
     RIGHT(A1;3)
   ;
     IF(
       RIGHT(A1;3) = " de"
     ;
       RIGHT(A1;2)
     ;
       --Insert more nested If statements here--
     )
   )
 )
```

Data of the surnames can look like the following:

```
Name1 van de
Name1 van
Name1
Name1 Name2 van
Name1-Name2 Name3 van de
Name1 Name2 Name3
```

What I want:

```
  OriginalName   |  Name  |  Prefix
-----------------|--------|----------
      a b        |   a    |    b
      a b c      |   a    |    b c
```

Firstly this is a pretty inefficient method, but I automated the creating of this formula, so that wasn't a problem anymore. Now I found out there's a limit to the nested If statements one can have, and I have to exceed that limit.

How should I solve this problem?

I have an array with the possible prefixes. Maybe this will help?

Comment: Store all prefixes in an array ( or in a range) loop through said range with strings needing manipulation and loop through the array and do a chekc thats like "if cell = array(i) then do soemthing"

Comment: Are you doing this as a formula inside the cell, or in a macro? Are there always space characters between the prefix and the rest of the name? Is the 'body' of the name always a single word?

Comment: @DougCoats This would mean that for every name (which are around 9000), it has to check if there's one out of ~20 prefixes present, right? Wouldn't this be really time-consuming?

Comment: @Werrf Right now I was trying to do this with a formula inside the cells. There is always a space when there's a prefix. The body of the name can be multiple words.

Comment: @Grafit Id be willing to bet that it wouldnt take that long. Vba is fairly quick especially if youre working in arrays. Id be willing to bet it takes up to 4 to 5 seconds (if done in vba and not a worksheet thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the assumption that you wanted to separate the "van" and "de" *prefixes* from the rest of the name.  If I misunderstood, please provide more examples of your problem/question...

The following solution requires a helper column to determine where the "Prefix" starts, but you can hide it if necessary:

[image]

First, put my values in `A8:A9` (*van; de*) anywhere and name it `prefix` so it can be referenced in the following formulas.

The formula in `C1` is an **array formula** (use *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>*):

```
=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(prefix,A1)),SEARCH(prefix,A1)))
```

The formula in `D1` and `E1` or normal formulas:

```
=IF(C1>0,LEFT(A1,C1-2),A1)
=IF(C1>0,MID(A1,C1,LEN(A1)),"")
```

Comment: Works pretty fine. One question though. When someone's name is `Name1 Demas Name3`, the formula thinks `Demas Name3` is the prefix. Is there a way to make sure it doesn't mix this up?

Comment: Put a space on the end of the `de ` value in your `prefix` array.  Then change the **array formula** to `=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(prefix,A2&" ")),SEARCH(prefix,A2&" ")))`. ... _OH_ ... and maybe switch the `SEARCH` function for the `FIND` function for **case-sensitive** searching... well, that'll only help slightly...

Answer (score 2):

Put your list ***in order of the longest surname to the shortest***.  I put mine in E1:E3.

Then use this array formula:

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,INDEX($E$1:$E$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1)),0)),""),A1))
```

Then to get the Surname:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1)),0)),"")
```

Being an array formulas they need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: This formula is a big help! It is definitely going in the right direction. Now I also want only the prefixes in a different column. Can I make this happen with a formula like this as well?

Comment: Sure just put the `INDEX()` function part in another column, and enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter as it returns the surname to the SUBSTITUTE function.

Comment: Also it is not appropriate on this site to change the question with new requests after getting answers as it nullifies the answers and opens them up for down votes.  Please put your question back to the original.  If my comment above does not answer your second request please ask a new question. @Grafit

Comment: I tried changing the reference of the `INDEX()` part to the column with the results I created with your original solution. Works well for the prefixes, but row 4 returns `craner` right now. I don't have a column available with only all surnames.

Comment: I didn't mean to change my question. From your answer I noticed my question was not clear enough since splitting the prefixes was my original wish.

Comment: Next time please ensure all your requirements are present at the start. @Grafit

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but I done this yesterday and didn't have time to submit it (had to run for the bus).

All Prefix values have a space before them...

[image]

Column B formula (Array formula - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in formula bar)
`=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(A1,Prefix,""),MATCH(SMALL(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,Prefix,"")),1),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,Prefix,"")),0))`

Column C formula - `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,""))`